# Nightwatch waitForElementVisible - abortOnFailure parameter set to false - test exit status non-zero

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am using the `waitForElementVisible(<selector>, <timeout>, false)` command from the [Nightwatch API docs](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/waitForElementVisible.html) and it is not behaving quite like I expected. How can I tweak this code in order to get the intended behavior?

Intended behavior:

> - call `.waitForElementVisible('foobar', 10, false)`
> - see command fail and continue execution with the next command
> - all other commands pass
> - see exit status of 0 from script

Actual behavior:

> - call `.waitForElementVisible('foobar', 10, false)`
> - see command fail and continue execution with the next command
> - all other commands pass
> - see exit status of 1 from script

Here is example code to reproduce

```
module.exports = {
  tags: ['smoke'],

  before: browser =>
    browser
      .maximizeWindow('current').url('https://google.com'),

  after: browser => browser.end(),

  'smoke test': browser =>
    browser
      .waitForElementVisible('foobar', 10, false)
      .waitForElementVisible('img')
      .assert.visible('img'),
};
```

And here is the console output from running that command:

```
Starting selenium server in parallel mode... started - PID:  75459

Started child process for: 01_smoke 
 01_smoke   \n
 01_smoke   [01 Smoke] Test Suite
=========================
 01_smoke   
 01_smoke   Results for:  smoke test
 01_smoke   ✖ Timed out while waiting for element <foobar> to be present for 10 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"
 01_smoke       at Object.smokeTest [as smoke test] (/path/to/tests/01_smoke.js:12:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
 01_smoke   ✔ Element <img> was visible after 33 milliseconds.
 01_smoke   ✔ Testing if element <img> is visible.
 01_smoke   
 01_smoke   Retrying (1/3):  smoke test
 01_smoke   ✖ Timed out while waiting for element <foobar> to be present for 10 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"
 01_smoke       at Object.smokeTest [as smoke test] (/path/to/tests/01_smoke.js:12:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
 01_smoke   ✔ Element <img> was visible after 21 milliseconds.
 01_smoke   ✔ Testing if element <img> is visible.
 01_smoke   
 01_smoke   Retrying (2/3):  smoke test
 01_smoke   ✖ Timed out while waiting for element <foobar> to be present for 10 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"
 01_smoke       at Object.smokeTest [as smoke test] (/path/to/tests/01_smoke.js:12:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
 01_smoke   ✔ Element <img> was visible after 20 milliseconds.
 01_smoke   ✔ Testing if element <img> is visible.
 01_smoke   Retrying (3/3):  smoke test
 01_smoke   ✖ Timed out while waiting for element <foobar> to be present for 10 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"
 01_smoke       at Object.smokeTest [as smoke test] (/path/to/tests/01_smoke.js:12:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
 01_smoke   ✔ Element <img> was visible after 20 milliseconds.
 01_smoke   ✔ Testing if element <img> is visible.
 01_smoke   FAILED:  1 assertions failed and 2 passed (53ms)

  >> 01_smoke finished.  


 _________________________________________________

 TEST FAILURE:  1 assertions failed, 2 passed. (6.259s)

 ✖ 01_smoke

   - smoke test (53ms)
   Timed out while waiting for element <foobar> to be present for 10 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"
       at Object.smokeTest [as smoke test] (/path/to/tests/01_smoke.js:12:8)
       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and that's the way it should be! I think you misinterpreted the way the `abortOnFailure` flag works for the [waitForVisible](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#waitForElementVisible) command. The `false` flag only gives the method the character *to be evaluated by the test-runner as a non-breaking
step*. But that doesn't mean it doesn't keep count of that step as being a failed step.

**Note:** A similar thing happens in the [assert/verify](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#assertions) case (*where `verify` is a non-breaking assertion, similar to the `abortOnFailure: false` parameter for `waitForElementVisible`*).

---

I can see where one would get that impression though. If you read the API call's description it said:

> If the element fails to be present and visible in the specified amount
>   of time, the test fails. You can change this by setting abortOnFailure
>   to false.

Which leaves you thinking that perhaps the test will end up passing, even though the `waitForVisible` command failed. ***But...*** the *Parameters* section of the API call comes to our aid, removing that false assumption:

> By the default if the element is not found the test will fail. ***Set
>   this to false if you wish for the test to continue even if the
>   assertion fails.*** To set this globally you can define a property
>   abortOnAssertionFailure in your globals.

---

***Lastly...*** where the DOCs might fail you, the code will never lie:

```
  process.on('exit', function (code) {
    var exitCode = code;

    if (exitCode === 0 && globalResults && (globalResults.errors > 0 || globalResults.failed > 0)) {
      exitCode = 1;
    }

    process.exit(exitCode);
  });
```

That above is the is a snippet Nightwatch's test-runner (`nightwatch/lib/runner/run.js`). See for yourself what it considers as valid `exit code 1` conditions.

Cheers!

Comment: This is a great response, thank you! However, it is a disappointing realization.. What this parameter leads you to believe is that the assertion result is passive and has no bearing on the exit status of the test. Is there any way to get this behavior in nightwatch?

Comment: @Jeremy all these _Selenium-based_ frameworks implement the same [W3C Webdriver standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/). The reasoning behind the `non-zero exit code` when a step, or assertion fails is that: _any failed step/assertion/etc failure will result in a **non-zero exit code**!_ This isn't the case only in **Nightwatch.js**... other similar frameworks have **the same behavior**.

Comment: The logical question here would be, why do you want a `non-zero exit code`, when your assertion has failed? That would mean that you're doctoring the tests to make them pass. Anyways, even if you have a `non-zero exit code` after the Nightwatch test run, you can doctor it (_post-run processing_) in some CI/CD system hook (_like, let's say Jenkins_). So if you really want to do it... you can! But, the behavior I explained above is valid all across the board.

Comment: Lastly, if I managed to answer all your questions, please take some time to [close the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks & cheers!

Comment: "Doctoring the test" is phrased a little unfairly.. I'm asking if there is a passive way to run an action in nightwatch. Due to timing, and inconsistent internet connections, something like a loading wheel for a request to fulfill can dismiss immediately or after some number of seconds. This would be a valid use case for checking a loading wheel appeared and then dismissed, or was never there at all (given the internet connection was strong). This is a sufficient answer though, so I'll close it out. Thanks again